# How can I hide the "Updates Available" button on the Tor Browser Bundle?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, firefox

I'm wondering if there's a way to modify the look of the Tor Browser Bundle. Specifically, if I want to hide the "Updates Available" button on the browser, does anyone know how I could go about doing that?

Comment: You can get rid of it by...updating!

Comment: Why would you want to hide this? Why would you want to use an older, less secure version?

Comment: I'm working for an app that's using a specific version of the browser, so they want to hide that for now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe TBB allows you to hide this feature.   You may update, and it'll stop displaying the update now (this will also increase security).